# Firebase Dynamic Links "No site has been created in Firebase Hosting"

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to add a url prefix for dynamic links in Firebase but I'm getting this error:

[image]

But I don't understand this because I think a site has been created:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

First off, a domain for URL prefix should only contain lowercase letters and numbers, 3 to 100 characters long.

It's also not possible to use **web.app** or **firebaseapp.com** domains, because the are owned by Firebase and there's no way to modify their configuration.

On the other hand, you may use the domain **page.link** provided by Firebase for free or use your own domain hosted in Firebase Hosting.

Lastly, be mindful that Firebase Dynamic Links is deprecated and should not be adopted in projects that don't already use it. This service will shut down on August 25, 2025.

Comment: In that case is there any way to modify the apple-app-site-association file for the page.link domain?

Comment: I think it's possible using this solution: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1169#issuecomment-588563112

Comment: That solution requires a custom domain. That’s why I was trying to use the web.app domain but I guess I’ll need to look into how to use an actual custom domain that I own.

Comment: Yeah. You're correct. That's for custom domain.